# Force Uniform Constructor and Method Annotation Values?

Tags: java, methods, reflection, constructor, annotations

I'm writing a custom API using `Reflection` to save Objects to file. I have the following class structure:

```
@Constructor
public XYZPOJO(@Key(key = "word") String word, @Key(key = "variations") ArrayList<String> varList) {
    this.word = word;
    this.varList = varList;
}


String word;
ArrayList<String> varList = new ArrayList<String>();


@Key(key = "word")
public String getWord() {
    return word;
}

@Key(key = "variations")
public ArrayList<String> getVarList() {
    return varList;
}
```

When saving Object to file, my program retrieves each method annotated with `@Key`, invokes method and saves invoked value to file using the value of `@Key` as the property name. Later, when I want to construct instance of Object it will search for constructor annotated with `@Constructor` and then retrieve value of `@Key` of each parameter in constructor and retrieve value of key (property) from file.

My main issue is that for every field I want to persist I need  to duplicate the `@Key` annotation (and value) before each method and before the corresponding parameter in constructor. Moreover, if both the constructor/method annotation do not match exactly it will fail to instantiate Object. It is very easy to accidentally copy the wrong values.

Is there a way to define each `@Key` just once?

I was thinking of adding `@Key` just once before each field I wish to persist however I believe (please correct me if I'm wrong) that I would no longer be able to instantiate class via constructor (I believe I would need to instantiate class by directly setting value of each field via reflection, thereby circumventing constructor, correct?). However, this is not ideal since the constructor performs certain necessary functions before the class is instantiated.

What other solution(s) are there?

Thanks!

Comment: You could make your life a lot easier by serializing this to JSON instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @ernest_k ya I know but I kind of already reinvented the wheel before I learnt about other persistence frameworks :) Right now my custom API has several advantages over other frameworks. For example, it uses key/value format and is much easier to read and reason about. In either case, I'd like to complete the final touches because it is basically done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that like every other library for serialization (or just switch to one of these libraries, as they all support everything you do), so possible solutions:

1. Skip annotation by default and just use name of getter (like `getMoney` -> `money`) and use annotation only in constructor. And on getter if you want to use other name in serialized form. Additionally you can look for field with same name to check annotations on it too, but it's optional and not needed.
2. Annotate only parameters in constructor but allow to set both name and property name (by default you can assume that name == property unless someone provided both values) And later you can change it to getter method name, like that `money` -> `getMoney` (just add `get` and make first letter upper case)
3. Apply 1st idea but also use parameter names from constructor that are available in runtime if someone compiles code with `-parameters` flag. And then you don't need any annotation, unless you want to use different name in serialized form, then just add annotation to only field/getter.

Note: 
Typical libraries just scan for public methods to find properties. So they look for methods that starts with `get` or `is` followed by upper case letter, that have no arguments and some return type. As typical data class will look like that.

Comment: @Goto_Final **Regarding 1)** How to find matching getters of field? Also, the annotation in constructor will need to match the name of field, correct? **Regarding 2)** What is 'name'? If I only annotate parameter how will I know value of field? **Regarding 3)** This would only work if the parameter name in constructor match the field names in class, correct? Thanks!

Comment: yes, all solution would expect that names are matching between different declarations, but in all solutions you can still provide custom names when needed

Comment: @AlanCook All libraries just scan for public methods to find methods that starts with `get` or `is` followed by upper case letter, that have no arguments and some return type. And then often finding field is not even needed, unless to check for additional annotations, but they can be on getter too. As you just work on "properties" then, will edit answer a bit.

Comment: Thanks. Upvoted and accepted! I asked a follow up question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60512364/determine-which-parameter-in-constructor-was-used-to-set-a-specific-field-in-cla thanks for your assistance..

Comment: Usually, the libraries don’t look for those methods on their own but use something like [`Introspector.getBeanInfo(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/beans/Introspector.html#getBeanInfo(java.lang.Class)), followed by [`BeanInfo.getPropertyDescriptors()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/beans/BeanInfo.html#getPropertyDescriptors()). There are lots of long-established mechanisms for customization here, while the default behavior of just using methods named `get…` or `is…` still applies.

Comment: @Holger if I try to look at bigger ones like jackson or gson I don't see any usages of these. I'm pretty sure many libraries prefer to do this manually to get more flexibility (and not fighting with memory leaks from this nice static cache when using app supporting multiple class loaders added/removed dynamically)

Comment: Even when doing it manually, there’s a point in using the same interfaces and annotations, rather than expecting classes to be have individual annotations for every yet-another-persistence-library…