# Determine Which Parameter in Constructor was used to Set a Specific Field in Class?

Tags: java, reflection, parameters, constructor, annotations

I'm working on developing a custom Java object persistence framework as I recently discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60501091/force-uniform-constructor-and-method-annotation-values).

One issue I am trying to solve is to force uniform annotation values accross constructor parameter and corresponding field in class.

Is it possible to know which parameter in constructor was used to set a specific field in class via reflection? For example, if constructor contains parameter `String textXYZ` and class contains field `String textABC` and in constructor I do: `textABC = textXYZ`  (so field/parameter have different names). Is it possible to know that the field `textABC` is associated with the constructor parameter `textXYZ` via reflection?

This would allow me to set annotation just on field and then deduce annotation value of parameter or vice versa..

Thanks

Comment: Even if they had the same name you couldn't get it with just reflection. I mean you can get it with reflection, but you'll need to also annotate the constructor parameters or something.

Comment: @Kayaman If they had the same name I could retrieve corresponding field via reflection using parameter name, no? I would annotate the field and get annotation of field.

Comment: Just like I said in that other question, all typical framework just work on names. It's enough.

Comment: @GotoFinal If I understand correctly typical frameworks will circumvent constructor and inject value using setter methods or by directly setting value of field (if this is possible). However, I don't want to circumvent the constructor as the constructor does necessary work before class could be used normally. I realize there might be other ways to achieve this but if it is possible to automatically retrieve the association between parameter of constructor and field (i.e, `textABC = textXYZ`) this would solve my problem.. Thanks!

Comment: @AlanCook no, most of current solutions, like jackson, fully support constructors, in all my work project I've always used constructor - as thats the only nice way to deserialize immutable objects with final field

Comment: @AlanCook only if you've compiled with debug info so the parameter names are kept in compilation (unless you annotate the parameters). I don't know of any framework that relies on that, since you'd have to use an extra compile switch to use the framework, and that's a big minus.

Comment: @Kayaman most of serializes now can work with this, like jakckon, but they just support few ways, like annotations on constructor to provide names or parameter names when possible.

Comment: [There’s a standard](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/beans/ConstructorProperties.html) for associating constructor parameters with properties…

Comment: @_Holger this requires I annotate every constructor with @ConstructorProperties annotation. I'm trying to avoid the need to do this as it is similar to requirement of annotating each parameter with same annotation of corresponding field (though a bit less prone to error)

Comment: @Kayaman I agree using extra compile switch is not ideal. I don't know why this functionality was not included in standard reflection operations.  You mentioned **I don't know of any framework that relies on that..** so if a constructor performs necessary work before class can be used there would  be no way to instantiate class via constructor using the other frameworks, correct ? How do the other frameworks inject values into Object?

Comment: @AlanCook it's not included normally because parameter names are extra metadata thought unnecessary in normal operations. While that's probably a mostly irrelevant optimization *now*, it's not the end of the world. If you look at for example Spring's constructor injection, it performs type-based injection if possible, otherwise it requires additional annotations on the parameters. A somewhat similar scenario to yours, except yours deteriorates to requiring annotations immediately due to few available types. You've taken quite a bite to chew for your project there.

Comment: @AlanCook The standard requires you exactly *one* annotation, the one at the constructor. It’s *your* decision to require an annotation *at each field*. So it’s your approach requiring tons of annotations.

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 7, there's an annotation exactly for that purpose: [`ConstructorParameters`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/management/ConstructorParameters.html). When placed on a constructor it  *shows how the parameters of that constructor correspond to the constructed object's getter methods*. You can reflectively inspect this annotation and then deduce what fields are related.
Of course, no one is forcing the constructor to be annotated, but that's the only *standard* way to correlate the fields and the ctor params. Many tool, like Jackson, Jsonb etc have their own annotations for the same purpose.